# How to link C++ code through the new compiler in V12?

Tags: external-calls, compiler

[The Advanced Compilation Topics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-uykbjQbyU&feature=youtu.be) talk in the WTC 2018 shows that one can easily link C++ code through the new compiler technology. This feature seems very useful as one can easily load existing C++ code into Mathematica without extensive modifications.

I followed the instruction but unable to make it work:

```
Needs["Compile`"]
```

Create the C++ source file

```
code="extern \"C\"
double square(double a)
{return a * a;}
";
WriteString["/tmp/e.cpp",code]
```

Compile the C++ code to llvm

```
Run["clang -S -Wno-everything -O3 -o /tmp/e.ll -emit-llvm -march=skylake /tmp/e.cpp"]
```

Import the llvm

```
llvmStr = Import["/tmp/e.ll", "Text"];
prog = Program[{
    LLVMString[llvmStr],
    Function[{Typed[arg1, "Real64"]}, 
     Native`PrimitiveFunction["square"][arg1]]
    }];
```

Compile to external program

```
fun = CompileToExternalFunction[prog]
```

I'm getting an error

> Compile: CompilerException. Type kind is not handled

I'm using Mathematica V12 on ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas about the error and the correct way to compile?

Comment: So basically an alternative to LibraryLink?  Very interested!

Comment: You ask ask a question, you don't explain a topic.

Comment: Hm, I just get unevaluated `Program` and `LLVMString`. Does one need some `Needs[]`?

Comment: @Ruslan You need to load Compile. I've updated the post.

Comment: The code is correct and actually works in the current development version. The released version does not have the necessary handling for floating point types, but it would probably work with `int square(int a)`

Comment: [`FunctionCompile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompile.html) with LLVM is finally here in 12.3 and [`FunctionCompileExportLibrary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompileExportLibrary.html). But there is not a `FunctionCompileImport...` yet. I've had a go at hacking the associations returned by `FunctionCompile` and substituting my own `ByteArray` of externally compiled llvm bitcode, but it blocks that by overwriting the array on evaluation. Also `Program` and `LLVMString` stay unevaluated in 12.3 so something must have changed there too.

Answer (score 7):

Too long for a comment, but this (undocumented) syntax works in version 12.3 with a minor modification and taking into account a renamed function, for example:

```
Needs["Compile`"]

llvmStr = "define double @square(double %0) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %2 = fmul double %0, %0
  ret double %2
}";

fun = CompileToCodeFunction[
   Program[{LLVMString[llvmStr]}, 
    Function[{Typed[arg1, "Real64"]}, 
     Native`PrimitiveFunction["square"][arg1]]]];

fun[12.]

(* 144. *)
```

For creating a DLL:

```
CompileToLibrary[
 Program[{LLVMString[llvmStr]}, 
  Function[{Typed[arg1, "Real64"]}, 
   Native`PrimitiveFunction["square"][arg1]]], 
 "LibraryName" -> "square"]
```

Comment: How would you then create a library from it? I tried `CompileToLibrary` but it always puts the library in some weird path. What if I want to create 'square.dll' at a specific path?

Comment: Something like `square = First[CompileToLibrary[..., "LibraryName" -> "square"]];
CopyFile[square, "C:\\temp\\square.dll"]`